# Why doesn't the second constructor take in a first constructor's object as input?

Tags: java, constructor

The problem:

[image]

Why doesn't the second constructor take in a first constructor's object as input?

And in a more general overview of the code, if you guys spot any problematic logic issues I'd be really thankful if you can point them out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Square3x3{
        private static final int DEF_VALUE = -1;
        private static final int ROW_COUNT = 3; 
        private static final int COL_COUNT = 3;
        private static final int LOWER_BOUND = 0;
        
        private int [][] _square;
        
        public Square3x3(){
        _square = new int [ROW_COUNT][COL_COUNT];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < ROW_COUNT ; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < COL_COUNT; j++)
            {
                _square[i][j] = DEF_VALUE;
                System.out.print(_square[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        }
        public Square3x3(int[][]array){
            int rows = array.length;
            int column;
            int colCount = 0;
            
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
                    colCount = j;
            }
            column = colCount;
            if (rows > ROW_COUNT || column > COL_COUNT){
                for (int k = 0; k < ROW_COUNT; k++)
                    for (int g = 0 ; g < COL_COUNT; g++){
                        _square[k][g] = array[k][g];
                    }
            }
            if (rows < 3 || column < 3){
                for (int x = 0; x > array.length; x++)
                    for (int y = 0 ; y > array.length; y++){
                         array[x][y] = -1;
                        }
                        
                    }
            if (rows == 3 && column == 3){
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                        _square[i][j] = array[i][j];
                    }
                    }
                }
                
            }    
        public Square3x3(Square3x3 other){
            if (other != null){
                other = new Square3x3();
                for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < COL_COUNT; j++){
                        this._square[i][j]=other._square[i][j];
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `other = new Square3x3();` you are re-initializing the object, the value is reset and you are coying the reset(-1) values

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking. Constructors must be with `new` and their appropriate parameters. A constructor will not call another constructor by itself (and unless you need another instance of the same object, it would make no sense to do so). Do you instead mean to have non-ctor methods called by a constructor?

Comment: Square3x3() outputs a 3x3 matrix whose elements are -1. if I create this type of object, how can I input it to Square3x3(int[][]array)?

Comment: For that, you would need a getter method for the `_square` property so that you can access it. But now I am even more confused about your actual issue is.

Comment: You were spot on with the Square3x3 (Square 3x3 other) constructor. as for the above question, they are unrelated.

Comment: remove `other = new Square3x3();` and add `this();`

Comment: @Sigma9, then what is your actual question? What is my answer not addressing?

Comment: @JoãoDias  your correction for the Square3x3 (Square 3x3 other) was great, but my main question is : Square3x3() outputs a 3x3 matrix whose elements are -1. if I create this type of object, how can I input it to Square3x3(int[][]array)?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understood your question but it seems to me that you have an issue with the constructor `public Square3x3(Square3x3 other)`. You are reseting the `other` object to a brand new `Square3x3` in the line `other = new Square3x3();` before copying its contents. What you want is the following:

```java
public Square3x3(Square3x3 other) {
    this();
    if (other != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL_COUNT; j++) {
                this._square[i][j] = other._square[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to make it simpler by using `System.arraycopy()`:

```java
public Square3x3(Square3x3 other) {
    this();
    if (other != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(other._square[i], 0, this._square[i], 0, COL_COUNT);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am still confused about what you really want to achieve with your question, but if you instantiate a `Square3x3` object and then for whatever reason you want to instantiate a new one by calling the `public Square3x3(int[][] array)` constructor then you need to expose a getter to access `_square` property contents (consider renaming it to `square`):

```java
public class Square3x3 {
    (...)

    public int[][] get_square() {
        return _square;
    }

    (...)
}
```

And then you can do the following:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square3x3 square = new Square3x3();
        Square3x3 newSquare = new Square3x3(square.get_square());
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `other = new Square3x3();` be removed?

Comment: Yup, I wrote it but forget to remove it from the code. Thanks for the hint @sittsering!

Answer (score 0):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083814/2d-array-constructor-that-take-array-less-equals-or-more-than-3x3/70084908#70084908) a few weeks ago about implementing the second constructor, but it seems here more details about a default and copy constructor have been added, so the solution should be modified.

> *Why doesn't the second constructor take in a first constructor's object as input?*

Because the input array of the second constructor needs to be *copied* to the field `square3x3`.  So the second constructor should invoke the default one `this()` and after that copy the contents of the input array as specified.

It's worth to note that usually the parameterless constructor invokes the constructor with argument and provides a default value but this is definitely not that case because this would result in *duplicate creation* of the array in these two constructors.

So, the first(default) constructor creates and populates the array field.
The second constructor deals with the copying the data from the input array.  The copy (third) constructor invokes the 2nd:

```java
public class Square3x3 {
    private int[][] square3x3;

    public Square3x3() {
        this.square3x3 = new int[][] {
           {-1, -1, -1},
           {-1, -1, -1},
           {-1, -1, -1}
        };
    }

    public Square3x3(int[][] array) {
        this();
        for (int i = 0, n = Math.min(3, array == null ? -1 : array.length); i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0, m = Math.min(3, array[i] == null ? -1 : array[i].length); j < m; j++) {
                square3x3[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Square3x3(Square3x3 other) {
        this(null == other ? null : other.square3x3);
    }

    public int[][] getSquare() {
        return square3x3;
    }
}
```

---

Also, initialization may be moved out of the default constructor and then it could be empty, and the 2nd constructor does not need to invoke it.  This saves a few lines of code but does not fully meet the specified requirements.

```java
public class Square3x3 {
    private int[][] square3x3 = {
       {-1, -1, -1},
       {-1, -1, -1},
       {-1, -1, -1}
    };

    public Square3x3() {
        // empty, provided just for invocation
    }

    public Square3x3(int[][] array) {
        for (int i = 0, n = Math.min(3, array == null ? -1 : array.length); i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0, m = Math.min(3, array[i] == null ? -1 : array[i].length); j < m; j++) {
                square3x3[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Square3x3(Square3x3 other) {
        this(null == other ? null : other.square3x3);
    }
// ...
}
```

---

Tests:

```java
Square3x3 def = new Square3x3();
Square3x3 copy = new Square3x3((Square3x3) null); // casting needed to resolve ambiguity
Square3x3 arr = new Square3x3(new int[][]{{1, 2, 3, 4}, null, {-10}, {5, 6}});

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(def.getSquare()));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(copy.getSquare()));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr.getSquare()));
```

Output:

```
[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
[[1, 2, 3], [-1, -1, -1], [-10, -1, -1]]
```